# What can cause a web server to not find an XML file?

Tags: php, xml, webserver

I have a PHP script which reads from an xml file to generate a table. The first thing it does is check to make sure the file exists.

```
$path = getcwd();
if(file_exists($path.'\inc\php\kbs.xml')){
    $kbs = simplexml_load_file($path.'\inc\php\kbs.xml');
} else {
    echo "Error: No KB file found";
}
```

For some reason, intermittently, it doesn't find the file. I've tried removing the `file_exists` check all together (since I know the file does exist) but it still doesn't load the file at times. I can refresh the page and 7 times out of 10 it doesn't load, but sometimes it does.

I never ran into this problem during development, but once it went production (being used by maybe 200 users now) it started happening.

How do I go about troubleshooting this? (PHP 5.2.14 running on IIS)

**EDIT:** Error logs give me the following messages when it fails:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: kbs in <the path> on line 16
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in <the path> on line 16
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <the path> on line 16
```

line 16 is the first time the variable `$kbs` is accessed. Obviously `$kbs` isn't set if the file isn't found.

Comment: Such issues are always tricky and mind-boggling when it sometimes work and sometimes not. Please try using absolute paths as suggested by @xdazz

Comment: I'm almost wishing it just didn't work at all, instead of intermittently :P

Comment: Of course, the error means that $kbs isn't set but does your script also outputs "Error: No KB file found"? If yes, then it is certain that file_exists() returned false. If no, it means that the XML file exists. And do not set $path to getcwd() for now; instead try giving the complete "absolute" path to your XML file.

Comment: I didn't know the actual path (as I don't have direct access to the server, just a network drive), but I copy pasta'd the path from the error logs and replaced the $path variable with it, now it seems to work. WTF? What's the difference?

Comment: Great, so that was the idea. When working with files, you should always use absolute paths unless you are certain on how to read them relatively. getcwd() gives you the current working directory, which can be different depending on how you are executing the script. The path "\inc\php\kbs.xml" couldn't be resolved because PHP was trying to resolve it from CWD which in this case is the directory from where you are calling the PHP script. Can you suggest how were you executing the PHP - browser URL, as a cronjob or from the command-line>

Comment: Through the browser. But I found the path by copying the value of the getcwd(), and pasting it into the string. getcwd() was giving me the right path, why did it only work some of the time?

Comment: Can you mention here the path given by getcwd()? Perhaps file_exists() works with absolute paths only, not sure though.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant. I'll just chalk it up to our server being poo. It works now so I'm satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the absolute path, relative path make things a mess.

Comment: Changed it to absolute path, same thing. Worked twice out of 10 refreshes.

Comment: @sicks turn your error_log level to `E_ALL`, and check the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Is the location relative to PHP? Do permissions allow the web server to see it?

Comment: I would assume permissions are fine, because it works SOME of the time. The location you see there is relative to the web page that's trying to access it. There's never any issue opening the file if you go to the path directly as well.